# Expression is always true, even though it isn't

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
if (!(sender is Button b)) return false;
if (!(sender is ToolStripMenuItem menuItem)) return false; // always true

switch (b.Name)
{
    //some code
}
```

So, the second line is always assumed to be true for some reason I can't determine. If I move it first and the first one second, then the button line is always assumed true. No matter which line I put second, it's always assumed always true, but not if it's first.

I am trying to understand why is that happening and how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Given that the code above is doing exactly what you've asked it to do, it is hard for someone to give a good answer if you don't state what you *expect* it to do. Right now it says, "if `sender` is not a `Button`, return `false`". Then the next line says "if `sender` is not a `ToolStripMenuItem` return `false`". It seems pretty clear that if we make it past the first condition, then `sender` is definitely a `Button`. So it's definitely not going to be a `ToolStripMenuItem`. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment and requirement to execute code depending on which type `sender` is, how about this...

```
switch (sender)
{
    case Button b:
        //Do button stuff;
        break;
    case ToolStripMenuItem menuItem:
        //Do menu item stuff;
        break;
    default:
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first line guarantees that `sender` is `Button`.

That means it cannot also be `ToolStripMenuItem`, so the second check will always succeed.

Comment: Is there any way to check if the object is different types of control? My goal is to display different stuff depending on which control it was called from.

Comment: @user9248102: Yes; that's what your code is doing.  But it cannot be two different classes at once; your code makes no sense.  You may be looking for the OR operator.

Comment: I already tried OR operator like this `if (!(sender is Button b) || !(sender is ToolStripMenuItem menuItem)) return false;` but same result.

Comment: @user9248102: Think about what your code means.  At least one of those OR branches will still always be true.  You need to move the `!` to make your code actually make sense.  Read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: I think that you need compare to the typeof unless to write the class directly. Or try with instanceof

Comment: @Mauri: No, you don't.  And C# doesn't have an `instanceof` keyword.

Comment: @SLaks why you don’t want to compare to the typeoff? Something like sender.GetType().equal(typeOf(Button)) // I m with my phone and don’t have intellicense

Comment: @Mauri: No; you just need the `is` operator.  Comparing `typeof` won't include derived classes.

Comment: @SLaks here is what i have in my mind, yesterday i was on my phone and i cant verify or write the code. I will put this as a new Answer